# Is there a way of working with Bluetooth Low Energy on iOS, lower level than Core Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to see the exact byte-after-byte data received in a BLE packet on iOS.

Core Bluetooth Framework only gives me a `advertisementData` dictionary for found peripherals (My iPhone acts for the central device). Is there a way to see it on a lower level?

Comment: Not on iOS, you'll only have a high level.

Comment: bluetooth is a fragmented subject in apple's api.
some bluetooth functionality can be found under AVFoundation. check it out.